# Exponential Fitting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting, curve, exponential

I have a data set with two columns and I want to fit to an exponential curve and show the equation on the chart.
Could you please help me with the code?

```
x<-1:6
y<-c(86000,114597,165576,207467,328745,531531)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(colour=" dark blue")+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls",se = F)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  theme_economist()+
  xlab("Grade")+
  ylab("Salary avg")
```

when I try to use nls  I can not see the curve on ggplot.

Comment: You can conveniently do that with the **ggpmisc** package, I think.

Comment: is there a particular function to look at? (`ggpmisc` has a lot of stuff in it.) Does it work for `glm`/`nls` fits (some of the frameworks I've seen work only for `lm`)

Comment: Can you help me with the code? I am new with R programming, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=1:6,
      y=c(86000,114597,165576,207467,328745,531531))
gg0 <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(colour=" dark blue")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  ggthemes::theme_economist()+
  xlab("Grade")+
  ylab("Salary avg")
```

One way to do it is to fit a GLM with Gaussian family and log link:

```r
gg0 + geom_smooth(method="glm",
    formula=y~x,
    method.args=list(family=gaussian(link="log")))
```

You can use `nls`, but it's a little tricky.  I used a self-starting method here, but (1) had to install an archived package, (2) had to specify `start` anyway (I think it's ignored but needs to be there)

```r
## remotes::install_version("drLumi",version="0.1.2")
gg0 + geom_smooth(method="nls",
    formula=y~drLumi::SSexp(x,b,y0), 
     se=FALSE,
     method.args=list(start=list(b=1,y0=1)))
```

Incomplete attempt to extract regression equation:

```r
g1 <- glm(y~x, data=df, family=gaussian(link="log"))
library(latex2exp)
library(equatiomatic)
s <- TeX(extract_eq(g1,ital_vars=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks!!! And how can show that equation on chart? just to know exponential and y value to fit the curve

Comment: Someone else will have to help with that. (You can fit `glm` or `nls` outside of `ggplot2` to retrieve the coefficients)